# Is there a way you can take a partial screenshots programmatically with adb?

Tags: python, android, android-emulator, bots, adb

I am writing the code of a bot on a singleplayer game.

The slowest part of the code is the part where it takes the screenshot. So, I was wondering if there exist a way to take only the screenshot of a region of the screen, like in pyautogui.screenshot.

I use python with pure-python-adb and Bluestacks 5 to run the game, but I am ready to change any of these if there is the possibility of taking partial screenshots in any other environment.

Comment: I would recommend to check the project [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy). They manage to stream the display to the PC, so their way to capture the shown display data should be pretty fast.

Comment: @Robert Thank you Robert for the help! I forgot to mention that I would like to use my computer while the bot is running and so pyautogui doesn't fit my requirements.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your comment. I never talked about pyautogui.

Comment: I wrongly assumed that you were referring to take a screenshot with pyautogui, so I guess that there is a way to take a screenshot of the mirrored screen specifically with scrcpy.

Comment: I was more thinking about checking scrcoy how they capture the screen and implements something similar.

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)
can take screenshots of a single View instead of the entire screen if this helps you.

Check [View.writeImageToFile()](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py#L1126) to take View screenshots.

Also [take-screenshot](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public/blob/master/take-screenshot) could be of great help if you need to take screenshots faster or other methods don't allow you to take the screenshot because it's not finding an idle state.